# How to make delete and select in a single database call?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am developing todo application. My delete mapping looks as below:

```
@DeleteMapping("/remove-todo")
    public ResponseEntity<?> removeTodo(@RequestParam("todo_id") String id, Authentication authentication) {
        SecurityUser user = (SecurityUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
        todoDAO.deleteTodo(id, user.getUserId())
        List<Todo> todos = todoDAO.getTodosByUserId(user.getUserId());
        return todos;
    }
```

deleteTodo and getTodosByUserId

```
    @Override
    public Todo deleteTodo(String id, String userId) {
        String sql = "delete from todo where id = ? and userId = ? returning *";
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{id, userId}, new TodoMapper());
        }catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e){
            System.out.println("NO ResultSet Found");
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public List<Todo> getTodosByUserId(String userId) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from todo where userId = ?",
                new TodoMapper(), userId);
    }
```

I am making two database calls first for deleting todo and then selecting all user todos.
How can I combine these two methods into single query? Can I do it with batchUpdate?

Comment: Is there any benefit to do so?

Comment: Yes, because I do select after update and create also.

Comment: It is unlikely that you can. Deleting a specific record and then returning the other records are two different operations that should be executed separately. Also, batch execution is not for selecting records.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `delete` and `list` method into a single method. `jdbcTemplate.update` method is recommended for `INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE`.

```
public List<Todo> deleteTodo(String id, String userId) {
    String sql = "delete from todo where id = ? and userId = ?";
    try {
        if (jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]{id, userId}, new TodoMapper()) == 1) {
            return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from todo where userId = ?",
                new TodoMapper(), userId);
        }
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e){
        System.out.println("NO ResultSet Found");
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```